Can we connect Instagram with Node.js to receive and send messages?
I've created a Node.js API that receives and send messages from/to my Facebook page, its a chat-bot connected with Open AI for a restaurant. I want to do the same for the Instagram, I've Instagram Business Account which is new (for testing). I've been going through the documentation and trying to connect it with Facebook Page Directly but it's not working. Is there a way to just send and receive messages from Instagram Account to an External API?
Some References and Documentations might help...

Yeah, you need a Facebook Developer account and to configure Webhooks; although it sounds like you already did that. Go to the Facebook Developers site and create a new app. Add the Instagram Graph API and Facebook Messenger products to your app. Configure your app and get an Access Token. You will need a Page Access Token to access the Instagram API. Go to the Graph API Explorer. Select your app and get a Page Access Token by making a request for your Facebook Page. Exchange the short-lived token for a long-lived token using the Facebook token endpoint. Use the Page Access Token to get an Instagram User Access Token via the Instagram Graph API.
In Node.js, use axios and node-fetch with the Instagram Graph-API.
Docs can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-facebook-login
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-facebook-login
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
